# grep and sed - replace all instances of a string

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a bash script I'm writing that greps for a filepath.  I want to be able to use the output of the grep to replace each instance of the old filepath with the new filepath.

Example:

`grep -R "/~test/dev/portal" .`

I want to be able to pipe this output into sed to replace each instance of "/~test/dev/portal/" with "/apps/portal/" (keep in mind, the output of the grep is typically more than one file)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check on ServerFault for these kind of answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grep -ZlR "/~test/dev/portal" . | xargs -0 -l1 sed -i 's:/~test/dev/portal/:/apps/portal/:g'
```

Comment: `grep -Z | xargs -0` just in case

Comment: Dennis, good arguments! I haven't even thought about using them for this (I guess I have to study the man pages more). `grep -ZlR "/~test/dev/portal" . | xargs -0 -l1 sed -i 's:/~test/dev/portal/:/apps/portal/:g'`